# Calculating actual flop/core when using actual memory bandwidth

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, hpc, flops, memory-bandwidth

I want to calculate the actual amount of mflop/s/core using the following information:

1. I have measured actual amount of memory bandwidth of each core in 1 node  which is 4371 MB/s.
2. I have also measured mflop/s/core on one node if I use only one core on a node(in this case the whole memory of node would be available for that core), the result is 2094.45. So I measured the memory bandwidth which was available for that core = 10812.3 MB/s

So now I want to calculate the actual mflop/s/core when the core has it's real memory bandwidth (4371MB/s).

Do you think it would be correct if I calculate it like this:

actual mflop/s/core= (mflop/s/core * actual memory bw) / used memory bandwidth

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the units are not very clear: flop is "floating operation", so you refer to "floating operation per core" -- is it really what you mean? usually people are interested in speed of processing, and measure it in flop/s (or simply flops) -- floating operations per second. And if you need so, it could be flops per second per a core, of course. Then, flop/core wouldn't be X seconds (2094.45s).

Comment: Unless, you imply some speed of your cores (which is some constant, S flops). Then surely flop = S * time, N flop of the process is proportional to time of the process T seconds..

Comment: @xealits Yes, I mean mflop/s/core (million of floating point operations per second per core)

Comment: ok. Then, your formula should be right, if the memory bandwidth is the bottleneck in the process. If memory is not limited, then the cores should work at their max speed.
So, could you specify how you measured the memory bandwidth and mflop/s/core? What do you do in the 1) and 2) cases? You run the same process on all cores in 1) VS one core in 2)? And how many cores are there?

Comment: @xealits for the first item, I've measured memoryBW on 1 node-16cores(the node can have at most 16cores ), then I can see how much memoryBW each core can have realistically. For second item, I've measured mflop/s/core on 1 node-1core and measured memoryBW on that core as well. Then I could see when I use only one core in a node, how much memoryBW the core can have.